# Postgresql index size: penalty for composite type?

Tags: postgresql, index, size, composite-types

My question refers to Postgresql 12.2.

I have two almost identical tables, structure- and contentwise, the main difference being that the primary key of the second table is a composite type, while the first table includes the components of the type directly.

```
CREATE TABLE first (
   a INTEGER,
   b SMALLINT,
   c SMALLINT,
   PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c),
   -- further fields: 3 SMALLINT, 6 INTEGER, 2 NUMERIC
);
CREATE TYPE abc_type AS (a INTEGER, b SMALLINT, c SMALLINT);
CREATE TABLE second (
   abc abc_type PRIMARY KEY,
   -- same further fields as above,
   extra BYTEA -- only 4 bytes long
);
```

Both tables contain the same number of records, roughly 2 billion.
The size of table `second` is 1.25 times the size of table `first`, which may be partially attributed to the extra field.

But what's really surprising (to me) is the 2.5 times increase of index `second_pkey` compared to index `first_pkey`.

```
SELECT
  t.tablename,
  indexname,
  c.reltuples AS num_rows,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(t.tablename)::text)) AS table_size,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(indexrelname)::text)) AS index_size
FROM pg_tables t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class c ON t.tablename=c.relname
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( SELECT c.relname AS ctablename, ipg.relname AS indexname, indexrelname FROM pg_index x
      JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = x.indrelid
      JOIN pg_class ipg ON ipg.oid = x.indexrelid
      JOIN pg_stat_all_indexes psai ON x.indexreliddd = psai.indexrelid )
    AS foo
  ON t.tablename = foo.ctablename
WHERE indexname in ('first_pkey','second_pkey')
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

```
 tablename |  indexname  |   num_rows    | table_size | index_size 
-----------+-------------+---------------+------------+------------
 first     | first_pkey  | 1.9596214e+09 | 165 GB     | 62 GB
 second    | second_pkey | 1.9596214e+09 | 205 GB     | 160 GB
```

**Is this difference in size a penalty for the composite type? Can it be avoided?**
The size might make a difference, not just regarding storage: 62 GB still fit into memory, while 160 GB is definitely beyond in my case.

Comment: I would stay away from custom (record) types like that. They are a nice idea, but don't really offer any benefits in my opinion.

Comment: The benefits are the same as for record types/objects in programming: In other tables, there are many fields of `abc_type`, and there are several functions handling `abc_type`. Not using `abc_type` means that queries become harder to read and harder to get right, since e.g. a comparison of two `abc_types` involves six fields and three comparisons in the first case and two fields and one comparison in the second case. I'd have expected that Postgresql is able to resolve internally the composite type as syntactic sugar and use it much like the separate fields.

Comment: Very good question. This fiddle shows it simply: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1ae27/1

Comment: @Climax Thanks for this nice demonstration! Really a pity that postgres doesn't handle this more efficiently.

Comment: @gernot it is a strange phenomenon. It must be a physical difference in how composite keys are stored versus complex keys.